# Suche ein Forum um auf Deutsch zu diskutieren

Tags: learning, online-resource

Ich möchte mein Deutsch verbessern, entweder durch Sprechen oder durch Schreiben. Gibt es ein Forum oder so, wo man etwas diskutieren kann?

Comment: Vielleicht möchtest du die Themen, über die du sprechen/schreiben möchtest ein wenig eingrenzen. Es gibt bestimmt Leute, die dir dann ein gut besuchtes deutsches Forum oder einen deutschsprachigen Chat zu diesen Themen nennen können.

Comment: Wenn du gut genug Deutsch kannst, um auch die alltägliche Umgangssprache zu verstehen, und wenn es dich nicht stört, dass wenig Wert auf korrekte Rechtschreibung und Grammatik gelegt, wird, dann suche einfach auf Facebook nach Gruppen mit deutschsprachigen Namen.

Answer (score 4):

Du kannst gerne bei uns [***hier im chat***](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/499/german-language) vorbeischauen. Wir versuchen, möglichst viel Deutsch zu schreiben (obwohl das oft nicht klappt).

#### Herzliche Einladung!

Answer (score 3):

Die üblichen Webseiten für Sprachaustausch ([Lang-8](http://lang-8.com/), [Italki](http://www.italki.com), mehr mit Google) bieten i.d.R. die Möglichkeit, Texte in der zu lernenden Sprache zu schreiben und sie von Muttersprachlern korrigieren zu lassen. Wenn man Glück hat, findet man auch jemanden, mit dem man über Skype usw. sprechen üben kann.

Ansonsten irgendein deutsches Forum zu einem Thema, das dich interessiert, suchen und einfach mitreden. Dann kriegst du zwar keine Korrekturen, aber Übung durch Praxis.

Answer (score 2):

Ich habe etwas gerade gefunden. vielleicht interessiert es euch.

http://www.voxopop.com/

Ihr könnt einfach suchen oder ihr könnt eine neue talkgruppe stellen

Es gibt auch diese website, darauf könnt ihr eine sprache mit muttersprachlern eintauschen

http://www.conversationexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Versuche es mal mit xing.de - Forum Deutschstunde.
Etwas Neues und Aufwendiges ist deutsch.info.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to check out leo.org, where they have a large chat section ("Quasselzimmer"). I am particularly fond of the Chrossover Chat, where German natives write in English and others in German.

Answer (score 1):

Jede Nachrichten-Seite hat eine Kommentar-Funktion.

1. Nachricht lesen + verstehen
2. Darüber diskutieren

spiegel.de
heise.de

Kommt auf deine Interessen an. Aber dadurch ist das Ganze thematisch abgegrenzt. Das macht das Lernen einfacher.